# Convert Timestamp in milliseconds to Timestamp in Seconds

Tags: java, timestamp

Given a timestamp in **milliseconds**, i want to convert it to an timestamp in **seconds**.

I want to do it in java

Comment: Did you consider dividing by 1000?

Comment: And where is the problem? Show your code.

Comment: You're asking how to divide a number by 1000 in Java, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `TimeUnit` to convert times, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long timestampMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timestampSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timestampMillis);
    System.out.println("Seconds: " + timestampSeconds);
}
```

The advantage with this, compared to simply dividing by 1000, is that you can easily adjust it to other units (days, hours, minutes) by calling other `toXXX` methods.

Comment: Small fix -> Timeunit should be TimeUnit.

Answer (score 7):

You need to simply divide the milliseconds value by 1000 and you will get the value in seconds.

Something like this:

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) ;
```

Comment: Why `% 60`? That's not what Stefanos asked for.